# Which data define an $SU(3)$ structure?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

Let $(z_1,\overline{z}_1,\dots, z_n,\overline{z}_n)$ be the coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ given by the identification $\mathbb{R}^{2n} \simeq \mathbb{C}^n$.
Define
$$
g =\left| dz_1 \right|^2+ \dots + \left| dz_n \right|^2 \\
\omega = \frac{i}{2} (dz_1 \wedge d \overline{z}_1+ \dots + dz_n \wedge d \overline{z}_n) \\
\gamma=dz_1 \wedge \dots \wedge dz_m
$$
The subgroup of $GL(2n)$ that stabilizes $g$ and $\omega$ is $U(n)$ ("2-out-of-3-property").
The subgroup of $GL(2n)$ that additionally stabilizes $\gamma$ is $SU(n)$.

In one source an $SU(3)$ structure on a manifold $M$ is given by specifying a $2$-form $\omega$ and a $3$-form $\gamma$ so that in any point $p \in M$ there exists an element in the frame bundle $L \in GL(M)_p$ that pulls back $\omega$ and $\gamma$ to the forms above.

> Question:
>   A priori, this should not be an $SU(3)$-structure, because the stabilizer of the forms $\omega$ and $\gamma$ from above is *bigger* than $SU(3)$.
>   Is this correct?

Is it maybe assumed that the manifold is a Riemannian manifold, and that $L \in GL(M)_p$ also pulls back the Riemannian metric to the $g$ defined above?
I can see that this would then be an $SU(3)$-structure.
Or is this a specialty of (complex) dimension 3, that here the stabilizer of $\omega$ and $\gamma$ is already *equal* to $SU(3)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:
A carefully chosen $3$-form and $2$-form in fact do have stabiliser $SU(3)$.

Let $V$ be a real vector space of dimension 6 over $\mathbb{R}$ and let $e^1$, $\dots$, $e^6$ be a basis of $V^*$.
Define
$$
\phi
=
e^1 \wedge e^3 \wedge e^5-
e^1 \wedge e^4 \wedge e^6-
e^2 \wedge e^3 \wedge e^6-
e^2 \wedge e^4 \wedge e^5.
$$
(This is $Re (dz^1 \wedge dz^2 \wedge dz^3)$ after choosing a suitable complex structure on $V$)
The *oriented* stabiliser of $\phi$ is $SL(3,\mathbb{C})$, i.e.
$$
GL_+(V) \cap Stab_{GL(V)} \phi
=
SL(3,\mathbb{C}).
$$
(A proof for this can be found in the appendix of *R. Bryant: On the geometry of almost complex 6-manifolds*)
If $\sigma \in \Lambda^2 V^*$ is non-degenerate, it has stabiliser $Sp(6)$ the endomorphism which stabilise both forms are $Sp(6) \cap SL(3,\mathbb{C})=SU(3)$.